# Type-able Functions From Factory Function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a generic function from a factory function that can be typed later. However, when I'm defining the factory function return I'm being forced to type it then:

```
export type TypeFunction<T> = (value: T) => T;

export type GeneratorFunction = {
    typeFunction: TypeFunction,
    // Generic type 'TypeFunction' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
}

export function generatorFunction(): GeneratorFunction {
    // ...
    return { typeFunction };
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call that returned `typeFunction` with the appropriate type be it string or otherwise like so:

```
const { typeFunction } = generatorFunction();
const s = typeFunction<string>('string');
const o = typeFunction<OtherType>(other);
```

How do I pass the ability to set this typing downstream?

Comment: try changing it to ```type TypeFunction = <T>(value: T) => T```

Comment: That was it! I had to adjust some typing in the `generatorFunction` to:
`const typeFunction: TypeFunction = <T = unknown>(value: T) => { return T; };`
Would you make that an answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments...

```js
type TypeFunction = <T>(value: T) => T
```

Comment: That is the one, thank you very much! I got messed up in the `generatorFunction` using `ReturnType<typeFunction>` when I didn't need to at all.